# Trying to merge records into 1 resultset

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a result set of Questions and Answers associated with each question:

```
var  myQs = from q in Questions  select new {q.QuestionID, q.ID, q.Description};

var myAs = from ad in AnswerDetails where ad.Answer.KeyID == 4590 select ad;
```

I'd like to build a list of all the questions and the answers (regardless if there is an answer for each question).

So I could have something like this:

> Question1Text | Question1Answer
>
> Question2Text |
>
> Question3Text | Question3Answer
>
> Question4Text | Queston4Answer
>
> Question5Text |

I'm using LinqPad and I can't get it to work using the `Concat` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to perform a left join. So called because the left part (questions, in your case) is required but the right part (answers) is optional. LINQ does not make this very concise, but it can be done.

You haven't provided what `AnswerDetails` looks like so I can only guess here:

```
var myQs = from q in Questions  select new {q.QuestionID, q.ID, q.Description};
var myAs = from ad in AnswerDetails where ad.Answer.KeyID == 4590 select ad;

var joined = from q in myQs
             join a in myAs on q.ID equals a.QuestionID into answers
             from a in answers.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 Text = q.Description,
                 Answer = a != null ? a.AnswerText : string.Empty
             };
```

Comment: This is the answer (or  a very close variation) of what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this ?

```
var questionWithAnswers = Questions
                         .Select(q => new { 
                                    Question = q,
                                    Answer = AnswerDetails
                                   .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Answer.KeyID == q.ID) ?? ""
                          }).ToList();

var resultSet = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, questionWithAnswers
                                                .Select(x => String.Format("{0} | {1}",x.Question.Description, x.Answer));
```

Comment: This is really close except I don't know the resultSet part.  I'm actually more interested in the questionWithAnswer.  How do I add the filter for the KeyID = 4590

Comment: don't you want to select all questions with their answers ? if you make a condition like `KeyID == 4590`, isn't it select same answer for each question?

Comment: All the Questions are static for each KeyID (i.e. person).  So there could be multiple people in this table and I'll be filtering on the KeyID so I return the set of questions and the answers.

Comment: @webdad3 understood. but you should specify that in your question.you didn't provide enough information about your problem.anyway I guess you find your answer

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your comment.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `concat` and `union` in `linq` to merge them, that `union` in addition `distinct` them, but `concat` merge them without `distinct`, but you need to two list in `same` type, for example you can do this to merge them

```
(from q in Questions  select new {code = q.QuestionID, id = q.ID, desc = q.Description})
.Union(from ad in AnswerDetails where ad.Answer.KeyID == 4590 select new {code = ad.??, id = ad.??, desc = ad.??})
```

fill `??` by fields on `answer` which you need, and are the same type as have you fetched from `Question` `(id, code, desc)`, if you can more fileds, from any table, you must add them to both `anonymouse` type which you select and return, and fill them by its default on table which you have not any value to fill them,

in addition, in your case, you need to do `left join`, for example something like this:

```
var query = (from q in Questions
    join u in AnswerDetails on q.ID equals u.QUESTION_FOREIGN_KEY into JoinedList
    from u in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {question = q, answer = u }
).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to left join of two lists becuase in answers list, you may not have answers for some questions:

```
  var result = (from qn in questions
                      join ad in answers on qn.ID equals ad.KeyId
                      into add
                      from ad2 in add.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { sd = qn.Description + "|" + ((ad2 == null) ? "" : ad2.text) }).ToList();
```